# How to make public website using tomcat server

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have some problem when try to make my website can access from internet.I have research and i can access it using IP: xxxx:8084.But now i want to access from my domain xxxx.com.I already pointed my domain to ip but it always "The requested resource is not found."
Anyone have soltution for this problem?Pls tell me

Comment: You need to export port 80, or call xxxx.com:8084.

Comment: Thanks Robert.Let me try

Comment: @NguyễnDuyPhú you need to change listening port `8084` to `80`. Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2008.I tried to change port to 80 but it conflic with port 80 from my IIS server